# insert command syntax error c#

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm trying to write into an Access db. The OLE DB connection is stored on the main form (mainFrm). I read and write using the same connection in other parts of my app. For some reason, at this one spot it says I have a syntax error. I have tried writing it different ways but still get the same error message

```
public OleDbConnection newCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MorganWillis\Documents\PlannerAppData\MainDB.accdb");`

ListViewItem newnote = new ListViewItem(nameTextBox.Text);
newnote.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
newnote.SubItems.Add(noteTextBox.Text)`

mainFrm.notesList.Items.Add(newnote);

string tempname = nameTextBox.Text;
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
string tempnote = noteTextBox.Text;

if(mainFrm.newCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    mainFrm.newCon.Open();

OleDbCommand noteCom = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Notes (noteName, noteDate, note)" + "VALUES (?,?,?)", mainFrm.newCon);

noteCom.Parameters.Add("noteName", OleDbType.Char, 50, "noteName").Value = tempname;
noteCom.Parameters.Add("noteDate", OleDbType.DBDate, 8, "noteDate").Value = now.ToShortDateString();
noteCom.Parameters.Add("note", OleDbType.Char, 1000, "note").Value = tempnote;

OleDbDataAdapter noteadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter();
noteadapt.InsertCommand = noteCom;
noteadapt.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

mainFrm.newCon.Close();

Close();
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. 

This is my error message

Comment: Try using named parameters

Comment: I thought you couldn't use named parameters with the OLE DB .net provider? At least that's what I read online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes was is a key word in access so it wouldn't let me use it for a table name but when I changed the table name it worked just fine Than you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have an errant `+` in the middle of your query.
It must be eliminated.

Comment: OleDbCommand noteCom = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Notes (noteName, noteDate, note)" + "VALUES (?,?,?)", mainFrm.newCon); changed it to this and it still doesn't work. keep getting the same error message. sorry i was trying to debug it and forgot to put the quotes back

Comment: sorry hit enter too soon. i fixed my comment. Thanks for your response!